# WordPress - displaying posts in a page

Tags: wordpress

I would like to display the posts the way they are shown when you have "show latest post" selected under reading settings.

I've tried using `query_posts`, but that displays the whole post, not the chunk that appears in the preview with the link at the bottom.

any ideas what I should be querying to get that?

---

**Edit**
I forgot to mention
I tried using `the_excerpt()`, but that doesn't show the image in the post. Also the `index.php` file is using the `the_content()` and it's displaying it the way I want it to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to show the whole post, you should use [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_excerpt) instead of `the_post()`
**Edit:**

From [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_content): 

`<?php the_content('Read more...'); ?>` Displays the content of the post and uses "Read more..." for the more link text when the  Quicktag is used.

Basically, use `the_content('your text for the link')` and add the quicktag to your article, this will automatically just show the text before